# Windows 10: Strange taskbar flickering and cursor delay for jumplists

Tags: windows-10, desktop, window-manager, jumplist

For the last couple of months, I've been facing a very strange flickering/delay issue in Windows 10 that I cannot resolve.

There are two problems:

1. Some time after every reboot, I have noticed that engaging the
   taskbar and then clicking anywhere else on the desktop causes **a strange flickering
   of the entire taskbar**. I've attached a GIF illustrating it. The
   problem arises regardless if I'm simply clicking on the taskbar and then on the
   desktop, or if I expand an app's jumplist and doing the same (which is the GIF version).
2. Usually in combination with the above, I have also noticed **a very annoying
   delay when opening the jumplists for apps**. When right-clicking on an
   app icon to expand its jump list, the mouse pointer gets stuck for a
   split second before the jump list opens up. This issue doesn't
   happen constantly, and I was unable to capture it now.

I've been trying my best to narrow down what's causing this. I'm running the very latest version of Windows 10 Home (x64), and the problem has persisted over several major updates. I have made sure to always update my NVIDIA drivers for my GTX 1070 Ti (currently running version 445.87), but that also hasn't helped. This means there might be some other app/process causing some issues.

I also run Stardock Fences 3 to customize my desktop, so I suspected this app's causing it. But I have tried disabling it to see if it has any effect, but no dice. Also did "sfc" and "chkdsk" in a terminal, but there are no issues to speak of. I figured "sfc" would see if my Explorer process is busted.

After rebooting my PC, the problem usually disappears and it has been very hard to see when/why it gets triggered. One thing that seems to be true is that it usually happens after I open up two windows and put them in side-by-side mode (WINDOWS+Left Arrow and WINDOWS+Right Arrow), for some reason. I have an ultrawide 21:9 monitor running in 3440x1440px, if it matters.

Any help on narrowing this issue down would be great, thanks in advance!

[image: Flickering example]

Answer (score 0):

God knows how many months later, it looks like I've found a solution to both the described problems; turning off the Geforce Experience overlay from the NVIDIA settings. After doing that, it seems the taskbar flickering is completely gone, and the jumplists do not cause any perceivable lag/"mouse locking" anymore!